# GPS alarm system for my boat

Tags: gps

I need a GPS alarm system for my boat, in case of theft. Maybe notifying me any anomaly on iPhone. How are they called "GPS Tracking" ?

I actually don't need to track my boat while sailing, but just knowing if it is moved away from its current mooring spot.

- Do I usually need to pay a monthly fee for these services?
- How long do the batteries last on such device?

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about GIS.